# What does the error "Could not create parent directory for lock file" mean?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have tried all answers which were in stackoverflow, but they didn't help.

[image]

Comment: "I have tried all answers which were in stackoverflow, but they didn't help".  Be specific.  Which answers did you try?  How did you try them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does the error "Could not create parent directory for lock file" mean?

I would have thought that the general meaning is self evident.

A lock file is a file.  Files can only be found or created in a directory; i.e. the "parent directory" that the message refers to.  The message says that it (Intellij) cannot *create* the parent directory.  (Presumably it is trying to create the directory because it is missing, and because it then wants to create a lock file.  Anyway, there will be a reason it is trying to create the directory.)

So why can't it create the parent directory?

Well we can't tell from the information you have provided, but there are a number of possible reasons:

1. The IDE may not have the necessary permissions.  For example, the parent of the directory may be read only.  (For the user account running the IDE.)
2. Something that is not a directory may exist with the same pathname as the parent directory.  For example, if the IDE was trying to create `C:/a/b/myLockFile` and there was an existing **file** named `C:/a/b`, then creating a directory `C:/a/b` *should* fail.
3. The parent of the parent may not exist.  For example, if the lock file pathname was `C:/a/b/myLockFile`, and the directory `C:/a` did not exist then the IDE might not be willing to create *that* directory.

(There are other possible but less likely explanations.)

Possible solutions include:

- Fixing permissions or creating the missing directories by hand.
- Figuring our why Intellij is trying to create a lockfile in a location that doesn't exist, or that you can't write to.